# Get list of libs my app requires on Linux

Tags: linux, yum, apt

Often I need to install supporting libraries on Linux to get my (or third party) app working. The process usually involves running `configure` and `apt/yum install` multiple times. Is this possible after the installation is over and the app was successfully compiled to get the list of all packages that were installed during the process by yum/apt? Or just yum or just apt if only some of them supports this.

Right now I have to use `history | grep apt` but this usually causes many invalid attempts to be included int he output.

Comment: Over on unix.stackexchange: [list packages by installation date](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/list-packages-by-installation-date)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the solution that answer mentions will output all sub packages, making a list rather huge, and you will never know what packages you really need. For example you need something that depends on crypt2.1 but next time they will depend on crypt2.2, but your list will still have crypt2.1 as it was in the output.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question. Do you want a list that's different from "the list of all packages that were installed during the process by yum/apt"?

Comment: @MarkPlotnickyes, to be precise: the list of packages I manually specified to be installed (in contrast to all packages that were installed as a result). Say I type `yum install kde gnome` then in my list I need only "kde, gnome" and not the zillion of it's siblings pulled in automatically.